# Connection Between Heroku and AWS EC2 Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-ec2

I have nodejs running app at Heroku and I created MongoDB server at EC2 and opened port 27017. I am using public ip address to connection and it makes delay. How can I fix that problem? I want to connect that two over internal network.

Answer (score 0):

Because they're on different servers, there is bound to be a delay. You can however reduce the delay by putting the servers in the same country (region)

Heroku servers are located mostly in US(Virginia), you can change your AWS servers to be near the same as well. Do check where the server's are located. A better alternative would be to use the mongodb addon: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab

Comment: Heroku's default region is US (Virginia) so saying they are "mostly in Europe" may lead to some confusion. The best thing is to verify the exact AWS region your Heroku servers are in, and place your other AWS resources in the same region: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/regions#view-the-list-of-available-regions

Comment: Changed my answer